# How can I use value from main select in Left Outer Join select - T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

In my below T-SQL Query I need to use `EFP_MessageCenter.MessageSender` from my main SELECT in the SELECT in my LEFT OUTER JOIN as the value where I have placed `<MessageSenderInitials>`.

When I set `(EFP_MessageCenter_1.MessageSender = EFP_MessageCenter.MessageSender)` or `(EFP_MessageCenter_1.MessageSender = MessageSenderInitials)` I get the error `The multi-part identifier "EFP_MessageCenter.MessageSender" could not be bound.`

How can I get this to work?

```
SELECT LOWER(EFP_MessageCenter.MessageSender) AS MessageSenderInitials
, MAX(SenderInfo.FullName) AS SenderFullName
, MAX(SenderInfo.ProfilePicture) AS SenderProfilePicture
, MAX(EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver.UserID) AS ReceiverID
, MAX(EFP_MessageCenter.MessageTimestamp) AS ChangeDate
, COUNT(DisplayCountSelect.Displayed) AS CountNonReadMessages
FROM EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver
INNER JOIN EFP_MessageCenter ON EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver.MessageID = EFP_MessageCenter.id 
INNER JOIN EFP_EmploymentUser AS SenderInfo ON EFP_MessageCenter.MessageSender = SenderInfo.Initials 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver_1.Displayed, EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver_1.UserID, EFP_MessageCenter_1.MessageSender
    FROM EFP_MessageCenter AS EFP_MessageCenter_1 
    INNER JOIN EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver AS EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver_1 ON EFP_MessageCenter_1.id = EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver_1.MessageID
    WHERE (EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver_1.Displayed = 0) AND (EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver_1.UserID = 65) AND (EFP_MessageCenter_1.MessageSender = '<MessageSenderInitials>')) 
    AS DisplayCountSelect 
    ON DisplayCountSelect.UserID = EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver.UserID
WHERE (EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver.UserID = 65) AND (EFP_MessageCenter.MessageType = 'SPECIFIC')
GROUP BY EFP_MessageCenter.MessageSender
ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
```

Comment: Your query is rather unwieldy and it would benefit from having all tables and columns consistently aliased, using small meaningful aliases not even longer ones! I can't see in your query where you have either assignments that are causing an error.

Comment: Note also you can use the same aliases in your outer-joined derived table, and I suspect this might be your issue if you think this is correlated - it's not, you would need to use `outer apply`, but it's not clear if that's your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a slight refactor of your query and changed the `outer join` to an an `outer apply`

It's not going to be 100% working I'm sure but should allow you to tweak it and include the correlation you need to.

I suspect you could move the `CountNonReadMessages` to a `count(*)` in the `apply` and possibly remove the aggregation, but that's just a guess.

```
select Lower(mc.MessageSender) as MessageSenderInitials
    , Max(s.FullName) as SenderFullName
    , Max(s.ProfilePicture) as SenderProfilePicture
    , Max(mr.UserID) as ReceiverID
    , Max(mc.MessageTimestamp) as ChangeDate
    , Count(s.Displayed) as CountNonReadMessages
from EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver mr
    join EFP_MessageCenter mc on mr.MessageID = mc.id 
    join EFP_EmploymentUser eu on mc.MessageSender = eu.Initials 
    outer apply (
        select mr.Displayed
        from EFP_MessageCenter mcx
        join EFP_MessageCenter_Receiver mrx on mcx.id = mrx.MessageID
        where mrx.Displayed = 0 
            and mrx.UserId=mr.UserId
            and mcx.UserID = 65 /* this should probably be correlated */
            and mcx.MessageSender = '<MessageSenderInitials>'
    ) s
where mr.UserID = 65 and mc.MessageType = 'SPECIFIC'
group by mc.MessageSender
order by ChangeDate desc
```